# java process memory is greater than xmx and MaxMetaspaceSize combined Why?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, centos7

I am running java process with below options.

```
-Xms2g -Xmx2g -Xss256k -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar
```

The res and %mem values ​​that can be checked with the top command in centos7 are

Use 2.6 GB, which is larger than 2.256 GB combined with xmx and XX:MaxMetaspaceSize .

Also, %mem is increasing slightly.

What I expected is that the java process memory does not exceed 2.256gb.

Why?

Comment: Off-heap space? There are many things that jvm uses for off-heap.

Comment: If so, is the continuous increase in off-heap due to my coding mistake?

Comment: I doubt it, in the rarest cases it could, but very rare. This is kind of normal, really.

Comment: When the heap area was monitored using jconsole, the heap area was being managed normally.

So it's not my coding mistake?